# Is curve25519 faster than spec256k1 on point multiplication?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Suppose $G_1, G_2$ are the base points on curve25519 and spec256k1, respectively. Point multiplication means to compute $kG_1$ and $kG_2$.

Then which curve is faster?

Comment: Refer to http://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-shortw-jacobian-0.html , point multiplication on spec256k1 needs 7M for double and 16M for add

Comment: http://hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-twisted-extended-1.html, point multiplication on twisted edwards curve need 8M for both add and double.

Comment: Beware that "variable base" scalar multiplication will have different performance characteristics than "fixed base" scalar multiplication due to the possibility of pre-computation of a particular base point for faster subsequent scalar multiplications.

Comment: This is generic question asking without the aim. For example Curve25519 when uses for DHKE the Montgomery Ladder beats all since Curve25519 has a Montgomery representation. So what is your aim so that you need to the two curves?